# Get Dropped Element value in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

i am Dropping a

```
<li draggable="true" >
    <img src="accordian/css/images/spreadsheet_AggAR.png" /> 
    Sales_Price  
</li>
```

On HTML table.

Now i want to get The value of Dropped Element  (in this case **Sales_Price**).
I write a drop event in backbone.js

here is my code:

```
events:{           
        'drop #tree' : 'dropTest'  ,
        'dragover #tree': function(ev) {
           ev.preventDefault();
           // alert("dragover!");    
        }
    },    
    dropTest: function(e) {
    //i want the value of dropped element
}
```

Kindly tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.dataTransfer`

```
  event {
      'dragstart #elem' : function(e) {
           var id = 'drag-'+(new Date()).getTime();
           $(this).attr('data-drag', id);
           e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("source", id);
      }
   }

dropTest: function(e){
   var source = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('source');      
   //console.log($('[data-id="'+source+'"]'));
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: `e.target` gave me the credentials of Dropped place.
i want the credentials  of dragged element.

Comment: are you using jquery-ui ?

Comment: yeah i am using Jquery